# ¿Cómo acceder a los elementos en json desde python?

Tags: python

actualmente tengo un pequeño problema con mi codigo creado en python.

Cuándo intento recorrer los elementos de la api me tira un error, y no se como solucionar este poblema.

El codigo para recorrer los elementos lo hago de la siguiente manera:

```
challenge = api["bundles"]["bundles"]["quests"]["name"]
```

De esta forma me devuelve un error no se como resolver este problema

El código completo es este:

```
import requests

response = requests.get("https://fnlookup-api.vercel.app/api?endpoint=challenges&season=current&lang=en")
data = response.json()

for api in data:
    challenge = api["bundles"]["bundles"]["quests"]["name"]
    print(challenge)
```

Comment: Bienvenida a StackOverflow. Te invito a hacer el [tour]. También sugiero que [edit] tu pregunta e incluyas: a) El valor que obtienes de la llamada al API (lo que hay en la variable response después de la llamada) y b) el mensaje exacto de error que estás obteniendo.

Comment: El error esta en no saber que recibes, descarga Postman y revisa que es lo que te regresa el get, si te regresa un objeto de objetos tienes que iterar sobre cada uno hasta obtener lo que quieres.

Comment: Hola Samantha. Creo que te vendría bien la librería request para tu propósito. Más info: https://j2logo.com/python/python-requests-peticiones-http/

Answer (score 0):

Buenas el problema que tienes es que la estructura del json no es equivalente al código que has escrito, la estructura es así:

Bundles(Padre)->Array[Bundles(hijo)->Array[quests->Array[name]]]

Por lo tanto, el código quedaría así:

```
import requests

response = requests.get("https://fnlookup-api.vercel.app/api? 
endpoint=challenges&season=current&lang=en")
data = response.json()

for api in data["bundles"]:#iteramos l'array de bundles
  for api2 in api["bundles"]: # iteramos l'array de bundles hijo
    for quests in api2["quests"]:# iteramos las quest
     challenge =quests["name"]# cogemos el nombre de cada quest
     print(challenge)
```

Una parte del resultado que saca (es muy largo):

Visit Breakwater Bay, Anvil Square, and Shattered Slabs

Destroy objects while drifting or boosting in a Nitro Drifter

Land at MEGA City and then reach top 25 players

Damage opponents with 3 different weapon types in a single match

Get air time on a Rogue bike

Deal damage with assault rifles

Open Chests

Finish top 10 in different matches

Discover named locations near MEGA City

Activate Augments in a single match

Restore health or gain shields while on a Grind Rail

Damage opponents with the Havoc Pump Shotgun

Knock back players with the Kinetic Blade

Answer (score 0):

Depende del formato del json. Ten en cuenta que detrás de la clave del json puedes encontrar un valor, otro objeto json o un array de objetos json. Si vas a encontrar un objeto json se puede utilizar la notación que has usado ya que no estas iterando, pero si vas encontrar un array de objetos json vas a tener que iterar sobre cada array. Por poner un ejemplo:

```
import json
datos=json.loads('{"a":{"b":1}}')
print ('clave: objeto json ',datos['a']['b'])
datos=json.loads('{"a":[{"b":1},{"b":2}]}')
print('clave: array de objetos json')
for dato in datos['a']:
    print (dato['b'])
```

Si no tienes muy claro si vas encontrar un valor, un objeto o un array de objetos puedes hacerlo de manera condicional en cada nivel usando type(). Si te devuelve una clase "str" o "int" es un valor, si te devuelve una clase dict es otro objeto y si te devuelve una clase list es un array e iteras.

```
import json
datos=json.loads('{"a":1}')
print ('clave: valor ',type(datos['a']))
datos=json.loads('{"a":{"b":1}}')
print ('clave: objeto json ',type(datos['a']))
datos=json.loads('{"a":[{"b":1},{"b":2}]}')
print('clave: array de objetos json',type(datos['a']))
```